# Setting up custom https sub domains with github pages?

Tags: github, https, dns, github-pages, dnsmasq

If we want the custom domain `example.com` with our github pages, then we just go into settings and add `example.com`, and assuming that we have already added the A records for `@` to our domain name registrar this just works IIUC.

Now if we also want a subdomain `sub.example.com` for another github repository do we enter `sub.example.com` in the repository settings panel for the custom domain? I assume this is all we have to do, assuming the A records for `sub` have already been setup?

I've tried it out and post doing it I get this github message:

> Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, sub.example.com, that's set up as an A record. We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing at [YOUR USERNAME].github.io. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/.

Why is github recommending this?  There is a reference URL included in the message, but it's a link to generic instructions on how to setup github custom domains, and there's nothing specific with respect to sub domains.

Comment: Have you tried the setting? And what problem did you get?

Comment: I just tried it.  First I added the A records to my domain provider for the sub domain I'm testing, and then I just set the the custom domain name, including the subdomain, on the github repository exactly as described in the question and it seems to be working, although it's taking a while to generate the https certificate.

Comment: Congratulations! Then it seems there's no problems, right?

Comment: Hopefully it's all good.  I don't see the https certificate generated yet, but it says to allow up to 24 hours for it to complete, so I'll check again tomorrow by 6 pm CST.

Comment: Now it says this:  Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, sub.example.com, that's set up as an A record. We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing at [YOUR USERNAME].github.io. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/.   ....

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on now. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message from GitHub is very clear, and according to its document:

> You can set up a custom subdomain, such as blog.example.com, by creating a **CNAME** record through your DNS provider.

That is, you should use CNAME record, not A record, and point it to [YOUR USERNAME].github.io.

Comment: I have this working now.  I have A records that allow Github to manage https setup for repositories that host their own content with their own gh-pages branch, and I'm pointing www to the top level domain using a CNAME record.

Comment: What I found confusing was the CNAME recommendation.  IIUC it is not necessarily the right thing.  If we want the subdomain to host its own content then we need the A records that allow github to manage the DNS for the subdomain.